# Как настроить домен третьего уровня

Tags: хостинг, домен, поддомены

У меня есть домен второго уровня *myname.ru*. Он находится на хосте *IP1*.
Я бы хотел сделать домен третьего уровня *sub.myname.ru*, но разместить его на отдельном сервере *IP2*, к тому же другого хостинга.

Что требуется для этого сделать?

Comment: Вы просто в DNS своей доменной зоны добавляете `A` запись с именем `sub` и IP2. Это если я вас правильно понял и вам не нужны будут `abc.sub.myname.ru`. Надеюсь тот кто держит DNS-сервера вашей зоны позволяет вносить любые правки в зоны

Comment: Спасибо, @Mike, перенеси свой комментарий в ответ, пожалуйста. Я отмечу вопрос как решённый

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В DNS своей доменной зоны добавьте запись типа `A` и именем `sub` с указанием требуемого IP адреса. что типа такого:

```
sub IN A 192.0.2.1
```